# Why does my sprite not work on iOS/Android, but works fine in Safari/Chrome?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, css-sprites

The images in question are on the bottom toolbar when you select a photo and then tap it to bring up the toolbar.  It's perfectly positioned in Safari, but nowhere in sight in mobile safari.  [Here's an example](http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/m/coolhaus/photos)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that the "Menu" on the page you provided gets chopped off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: in `http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/mobile/photoswipe.css` on the line `160` you overrided the `http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/mobile/images/photoswipe-icons.png` image with the address for HQ-icons (`http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/mobile/images/photoswipe-icons@2x.png`) which is getting 404 error.

So, the solution is to put the needed image where it must be or remove these styles so they wouldn't override the non-HQ image's address.

Comment: Awesome!  How did you figure that out?

Comment: At first I added style to add solid red background to the toolbar buttons, to make sure they are visible and this is an issue only in background-image, then I added `!important` to the rule with the background-image declaration to see if it overrided somewhere later, and then, after It become obvious that it's overridden, I searched the stylesheet to find what selectors can override this rule, found the rule with HQ sprite and tried to open it in browser — that's how I figured out that it's missing :)

Comment: Cool, I really appreciate your help solving this and explaining the process.